# MySQL max_allowed_packet param whats the catch?

Tags: mysql, configuration, performance

I need to increase the max_allowed_packet param, to fit some theoretically very large items. If I set this param to say 10M, what price if any am I paying compared to setting it to 1M or 4M.
Thanks for any input!
Tomas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this explanation: `http://www.astahost.com/info.php/max_allowed_packet-mysql_t2725.html`

> It's safe to increase the value of
>   this variable because the extra memory
>   is allocated only when needed. For
>   example, mysqld allocates more memory
>   only when you issue a long query or
>   when mysqld must return a large result
>   row. The small default value of the
>   variable is a precaution to catch
>   incorrect packets between the client
>   and server and also to ensure that you
>   don't run out of memory by using large
>   packets accidentally.

Also note that I read you have to change the value for both the mysql client and the mysql server.

Comment: Thanks, that was my guess too, but as they say, when you assume - you make an ass out of u and me. 
I'm using JDBC-java client, I'll look into if I need to set some param there.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest not touching this variable, instead adjusting your storage implementation to handle any size files using the default settings.

Can you see [here](http://www.dreamwerx.net/phpforum/?id=1) for an example.

Comment: Thnx, interesting reading, will keep that in mind. But it will seldomy happen that the files are that big, and they won't get read more than once (it's a JMS message).
//Tomas