# mysql max_allowed_packet setting effect on performance

Tags: mysql, performance

As per these posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295523/mysql-max-allowed-packet-param-whats-the-catch) and [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/45665/what-max-allowed-packet-is-big-enough-and-why-do-i-need-to-change-it/45667#45667?newreg=75d9309d81f84b0b947fa00d8fa07ef8) it seems there is no effect on setting max_allowed_packet to a higher value.
I would like to know if anyone observed any performance issues like increased response time, halting of other queries on a production setup.

Comment: Changing that setting only applies in a few cases.  Let's see your case.